# MitM-attack on RDP connection - how sophisticated can it get?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, rdp

So I know how MitM-Attacks work against RDP [now](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/163486/how-can-i-know-if-an-attack-is-still-valid-if-there-is-no-cve-for-it) and I have a bit of abstract knowledge about MitM-attacks in general. As far as I understand, as an attacker you want to listen to the traffic of your victim and manipulate the network packets in certain situations.

I wonder how sophisticated this kind of manipulation can be. When using RDP, users only see a video stream of the screen of the machine they are connected to. Would it be possible for an attacker to change the traffic in a way that:

a) a user sees something on his screen that is not happening?

b) a user does not see something that is happening on the screen?

Comment: Theoretically yes. It would be very difficult to pull off though so I would think for most people the threat is very low. The bad actor could either attack an endpoint or the actual RDP communication.

Comment: The big worry is the MITM attacker capturing the pasdword